# Can I change state from one slice to another slice in Redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

I have 2 slices, the first of which contains state errors and the second of which contains logic.

Is it possible to change the value state in the error slice from a logical slice?

**Error slice**

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const initialState = {
  error: false,
};

export const errorSlice = createSlice({
  name: "error",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setError: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setError } = errorSlice.actions;

export default errorSlice.reducer;
```

**Logical slice**

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const doSomething = (data) => {
  return (dispatch) => {
      dispatch(setData(data.text))
      // here I want dispatch setError from errorSlice
      // dispatch(setError(data.error))
  };
};

const initialState = {
  data: null,
};

export const logicalSlice = createSlice({
  name: "logical",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setData: (state, action) => {
      state.error = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const { setData } = logicalSlice.actions;

export default logicalSlice.reducer;
```

And I need to run it from a component with a single dispatch
`dispatch(doSomething(data))`

Is there such a possibility?

Thank you!